# Is it better to implement dedicated slab cache allocator over kmalloc?

Tags: linux, memory-management, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

In my linux kernel driver, I am concerned about memory fragmentation using kmalloc. Although kmalloc uses slab cache allocation underneath, is it better to implement a dedicated slab cache allocator?

Comment: kmalloc allocates continuous memory. If your driver implementation clutters memory, fix your driver.

Comment: @Jay-Pi Thanks for your response! I am using kmalloc for a ioctl read/write. I was just concerned if it may cause memory fragmentation. Is there a way I can measure fragmentation caused by a driver? I know proc/buddyinfo gives an overall picture but is there any tool which will give me info about one driver?

Comment: [Good introduction](https://events.static.linuxfound.org/sites/events/files/slides/slaballocators.pdf), [collection of stuff](https://elinux.org/Kernel_dynamic_memory_analysis), [Kernel newbies](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.18/vm/slub.html), [other allocators](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/273634549_An_Experimental_Comparison_Analysis_of_Kernel-level_Memory_Allocators/link/55357fb10cf20ea35f10d9ad/download). Is this enough for you?

Comment: You need hooks for the tool by compile the Kernel with according debug/tracing options. The according tool should then handle the recording/tracing part.

Comment: Use slab cache if you are frequently allocating/freeing identical sized blocks.

Comment: Can you point to a problem caused by "memory fragmentation"?